# Spyware propagation over wireless network? How to trace?

Tags: wireless-networking, malware, redirection, spyware

Recently at my company, we have been experiencing intermittent search redirects when connected to our wireless network.

I say intermittent because many times, simply disconnecting and reconnecting to the wireless network will resolve the problem. Sometimes it will disappear for a user and then reappear.

When hardwired in, there are no redirect issues. I have run many scans on the machines that are experiencing these redirects and they all come out clean.

My understanding is that there could be an infected machine somewhere on the wireless network that is spreading this issue. But whoever this user may be, they have not stepped forward and complained about redirects themselves.

Alternatively, could it be residing somewhere on one of our servers (if so, why no hardwired redirects)?

My question is this: 
Is there any way that I could possibly track/trace where this thing is coming from? Scanning every single computer connected to the wireless network would not be an easy option for the 'higher ups' to accept at this point in time and Im stuck trying to play whack-a-mole in the meantime.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked IP settings, done route traces or any other network discoveries while this is happening?

Perhaps you're intermittently connecting to a rogue or mis-configured wireless AP.

Comment: I have not actually run trace routes on the machines showing this, but it will certainly be something that I do from here on out. I had suspected a 'bad' wireless AP point as well. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Sorry for long wait. Turns out one of the AP points had been compromised.Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

techie007 has a point about intermittently connecting to a rouge or misconfigured wireless AP, somewhat. When a computer connects to a wireless network you choose that, and can only choose one at a time. Your DNS servers are probable cause. I say this because if they have been changed or tampered with that could cause intermittent redirects, especially if your alternative DNS servers have been changed. Check those in both the DNS server (if you have any) and also the router in question.

Traceroute may be a possible solution. However, to be positive that your wireless network is to blame, try one of the computers that have been redirected in a known good wireless network.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the advice. Ill report back if I find anything